# How to use index from JavaScript to create ColdFusion variable?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I was wondering if I can use for() loop in JavaScript to build dynamic ColdFusion variable that is used in my function. Here is example of what I have:

```
listTypes = ['a','b'];

    for(var i=0; i < listTypes.length; i++){
        getBldgs('#trim(getRec.st_'+listTypes[i]+'Bldg)#', '#trim(getRec.st_'+listTypes[i]+'Bldg)#', listTypes[i]+'Bldg');
    }
```

All what should be done in this process is replacing the index and call the function getBldgs() multiple times. I'm getting this error:

```
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

/'

The CFML compiler was processing:

    An expression beginning with trim, on line 327, column 32.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    The body of a cfoutput tag beginning on line 85, column 2.
```

If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: For that specific error, wrap your entire script with cfoutput tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have cfoutput around my function and still the same error.

Comment: Your goal is not clear.  The title says create CF from JS but your code suggests creating JS from CF.

Comment: @DanBracuk But I'm passing coldfusion variables in JS function.

Comment: With the single quotes around the parameters, you are passing a string which effectively winds up being `#trim(getRec.st_aBldg)#`.  Is that what you want to pass to the `getBldgs` function?

Comment: @snackboy Yes I'm trying to pass #trim(getRec.st_aBldg)# and  #trim(getRec.st_bBldg)#. Both should be built dynamically.

Comment: Based on what you have above (and adding `<script></script>` and `getBldgs` function) that's what the code is doing.  I'm not seeing an error.  But I am curious as to what you expect CF to be doing since you are simply passing a string value to the `getBldgs()` function.

Comment: @snackboy Those two variables that I'm trying to pass are cfquery columns. I'm not sure if that's possible to do this way. Sorry about missing that in my original question.

Comment: Okay.  I would move the listTypes loop to CF.  So your outer loop is the query, and the inner loop are your listTypes.  Then I would build your `getBldgs()` parameters in CF as well.  Then your javascript would just contain `getBlgs(#p1#,#p2#)` where p1 was defined as `<cfset p1 = trim(getRec['st_' & listType & 'Bldg'])#>`.  `listType` comes from your inner loop `<cfloop array=#listTypes# index=listType>`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @snackboy Yes, thanks for help!